# AngularJS: Only add ng-show attribute if some data exists

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

Rather than have two blocks of code which are almost identical (the difference being a single ng-show attribute if some data exists), is there a way to avoid the repetition and have ng-show be present on condition that the data is there?

**Current pseudo implementation**

```
<div ng-if="data value X exists">
   <div ng-show="data binded condition using X">
      stuff here... many LoC
   </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="data value X doesnt exist">
   <div>
      EXACT same stuff here but without the ng-show in the div above.
   </div>
</div>
```

**This could be much leaner**

```
   <div ng-show-attr-here-if-data-value-X-exists="data binded condition using X">
      stuff here
   </div>
```

Is this even possible?

I see ng-attr come up often when I google around this topic, but I seem to be having no luck with ng-show, most likely due to my own inexperience.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ng-if and ng-show on same element:

```
<div>
   <div ng-if="data value X exists" ng-show="data binded condition using X">
      stuff here... many LoC
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To be clear, I want the <div> element to display all of the time. I just don't want it to have the ng-show attribute "all of the time". Maybe my thinking here is fundamentally wrong.